# What are the assumptions of conducting a mediation analysis using structural equation modelling

Tags: panel-data, stata, fixed-effects-model, structural-equation-modeling, mediation

What are the core assumptions when doing mediation analysis in structural equation modelling? I am estimating the classic mediation model using SEM in panel data in Stata with fixed effects (image attached). Having found a relationship between X and Y in my earlier fixed effects regressions, I want to look at the importance of mediator variables in my data in explaining this relationship, i.e. does information on net worth mediate the relationship I observed between unemployment shocks and mental health scores. I know how to do this in my statistical program, but first I would like to know what the core assumptions (implicit or explicit) are in this kind of an analysis.

[image]

Comment: Such analyses usually need to assume no unmeasured confounding between mediator and outcome (dependent variable). You also require the usual exchangeability assumption for analyses not involving mediator.

Comment: Thanks for your response, could you please explain what you mean by the usual exchangeability assumption for analyses not involving the mediator?

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question, particularly with panel data and the possibility of controlling for fixed effects. One way to understand the assumption of mediation is with the analogy of an experimental treatment on the X variable, and this shock to the system would then be traced along the c' and the a*b paths. The same can be conceptualized in the panel data case by considering a cross-lagged panel model (or panel VAR in econometrics), where you can then trace the path of the earlier shock on future occasions (as is done with impulse response analysis in VAR literature). Some of the implications and meaning of fixed effects and impulse responses in data like yours are discussed extensively in Zyphur et al. (2020) parts one and two ([here](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1094428119847278) and [here](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1094428119847280)).